# Remove Android videoview black bar

Tags: android

I have a VideoView, which is rotated 90 degrees. This results in an ugly black bar on the side. Which would normally be under the MediaController (I think). I can't find an XML attribute to kill it and haven't found anything in VideoView documentation. I'm not having any luck with Google either because I'm probably not using good search terms, as I don't know what it is.
Anyone know how to get rid of this??

My code is simple. I have a parent layout with a VideoView in XML, both set to match parent. 
Java:

```
this.viewer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vid_view);
this.viewer.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Folder/" + video);
this.mc = new MediaController(this);
this.mc.setMediaPlayer(this.viewer);
this.viewer.setMediaController(this.mc);
this.viewer.requestFocus();
this.viewer.start();
```

[image: malformatted view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of a video may not match the aspect ratio of the screen, or the portion of the screen taken up by the `VideoView`.

Your choices are:

1. Use `android:gravity` to position the black bar, such as centering it for a "letterbox" effect, or
2. Try using negative margins, so portions of the too-long dimension lie outside the screen, though this will chop off those portions of the video

The latter technique works for camera previews; I have not tried it with videos and `VideoView`. It would also require some runtime calculations, unless you happen to know the aspect ratio of your videos in advance.

Comment: It's Friday. Centered it is. Maybe tomorrow I'll play with it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Wait are you the Mark Murphy from the busy coder's guide? If so I own a book or two of yours. I feel cool. Dunno why.

Comment: @user3029413: "Wait are you the Mark Murphy from the busy coder's guide?" -- yes. "If so I own a book or two of yours" -- thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I have similar issue but instead of the black bar on the right, I have it on bottom (or half on top and half on bottom if I use: `android:gravity="center" ` ). How is it possible to completely remove them and have full screen video? What is the reason of those black bars?

Comment: @Johny: "What is the reason of those black bars?" -- the [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) of your available screen space is different than the aspect ratio of the video. "How is it possible to completely remove them and have full screen video?" -- you can try the techniques that I outline in my question. Note that by doing so, you will cause some of the video to be cropped.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already tried some other techniques like `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` but in this way it just stretches the video instead of making it full screen smoothly. If I change the video resolutions will it make the trick? Can you also take a look in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536521/support-different-video-sizes-for-android/43587495#) ?

Comment: @Johny: "If I change the video resolutions will it make the trick?" -- no, because there are ~2 billion Android devices spread across thousands of device models, with dozens of different screen aspect ratios.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what is the best solution in this problem? It still confuse me how to get rid of those black bars because it doesn't appear on all phones.

Comment: @Johny: You can try the negative-margins approach. Calculate the size of the `VideoView` that you need that will fill the screen while maintaining the aspect ratio. That size will be bigger than the available space on one axis, and an exact match for the available space along the other axis. For the axis that is too big, calculate the difference in lengths, divide by two, and make that a negative margin on those sides, by adjusting your `LayoutParams` at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142504/discussion-between-johny-and-commonsware).

Comment: @CommonsWare "You can try the negative-margins approach. " Can you give a complete example please?