# Support different video sizes for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

I am creating an App that is playing a video (as splash screen) but I am confused which are the correct sizes for each different screen.

I have already checked a lot of answers [(this link was indeed helpful but still not clear)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) and official documentations but it is still confusing me.

I created the following folders:`raw-ldpi, raw-mdpi, raw-hdpi, raw-xhdpi, raw-xxhdpi, raw-xxxhdpi` BUT what are the **correct video sizes** for each of the above different folder?

For example for `raw-ldpi` what are the correct video dimensions? *(i.e 240 x 360)*

Answer (score 0):

I found out the following resolutions from this [site](http://www.v4c.org/en/content/basics-video-resolution) and [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) but I am not sure if those are the correct.

If someone knows or has experience with please let me know.

320 x 240

640 x 480

720 x 480

1280 x 720

1920 x 1080